# .htaccess permanent redirect to www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress instalation that is not redirecting urls not starting with www.

Example: http://example.com/dir/ doesn't send to http://www.example.com/dir/ instead goes to http://example.com/

How do I change the .htaccess below to always redirect to the page either using www or not?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Comment: did you tired from  /wp-admin/options-general.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More like a question for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Well anyway, if you are using cPanel, you can do a wildcard redirect from `Redirects` under `Domains` category.

But if not, try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: Where would I add this? To the beginning of the .hataccess?

Comment: Yes. Also, you can just add the last two lines after `RewriteEngine On` on your existing .htaccess

Comment: Nope doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Thanks Ruel. But the same happens. If I try http:// domain.com/dir/ it goes to http:// www.domain.com/ without /dir/

Comment: @Ruel - More like a question for WordPress Answers... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you have another definitions with RewriteCond and RewriteRule, you should move these ones to the top

Answer (score 11):

You should not have to modify your `.htaccess`; actually I would not recommend it.

Sounds like you simply have your values for WordPress address and Site address set correctly in your admin console in the *Settings > General* section:

[image: Screenshot showing WordPress' Settings > General section and the WordPress address and Site address]

Another option is to add the following 2 lines somewhere within your `/wp-config.php` file but before `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` *(and be sure not to use a trailing slash):*

```
define('WP_HOME',"http://www.example.com/dev");
define('WP_SITEURL',"http://www.example.com/dev");
```

I prefer this approach because I like to keep my configuration options in code whenever possible since it is easier to maintain that way than configuration options stored in the database.

Hope this helps.

-Mike

P.S. Next time you have a WordPress question, consider asking over at StackOverflow's sister site [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)? Lots of WordPress enthusiasts over the to help out.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the suggestions but this is a multi-site install and neither the URL settings in the administration or in the config file are set in this way. I'll be checking the wordpress.stackexchange.com site in the future.

Comment: @Pedro Reis - Sorry, you didn't say anything about it being multi-site in your question; that kind of information is critical. I wouldn't have spent time trying to answer if I'd known since I'm not experienced on multi-site.

Answer (score 5):

I got the correct answer from webmasters.stackexchange.com. This works perfectly! Thanks Ruel for pointing me to webmasters.stackexchange.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Then why didn't you choose your answer?

Comment: @IXN I did chhose the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly. Put this at the top of `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_HOME',"http://www.example.com/dev");
define('WP_SITEURL',"http://www.example.com/dev");
```