# Redirecting from http://domain to http://www.domain creates a loop because URL doesn't change

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, infinite-loop

I am trying to redirect from http://domain to http://www.domain directly on the application, but URL doesn't change, so when page is reloaded, it does again and again and becomes a loop.

Both `wp_redirect` (the function Wordpress uses) and myself (i used `header("Location: $url")`) fail to redirect and make loops.

When I try to redirect with `.htaccess` everything becomes a loop.

My app is on OpenShift and I use CloudFlare as a DNS server.

@edit

This is the .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This is the first lines of index.php

```
$subdomain = array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
if($subdomain != 'www'){
    $url = 'http://www.'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    header("Refresh:0; url=$url");
    //header('Location: http://google.com.br');
    exit();
}
```

When I use `Refresh` instead of `Location` it works until cache is saved. A few hours then.

Comment: Post your actual code. We can't just guess what you did.

Comment: I did nothing. it's the default settings. but i will post some code

Comment: There's nothing in your .htaccess to redirect the domain. How do you expect it to work?

Comment: @Mike If you simply go to `http://mydomain`, it will become a loop. `www.domain` works great. WordPress is already trying to redirect from `http://domain` to `http://www.domain` and it is causing a loop (I don't know why, but I found the redirect attempts on wp_redirect function). I am trying to do it myself, and also causes a loop.

Comment: You said in the question that the URL doesn't change, so I'm confused about what you mean. Can you describe what this "loop" is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess permanent redirect to www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160358/htaccess-permanent-redirect-to-www)

Comment: a loop is a redirect loop caused by the fact I am redirecting with `header()` and the URL doesn't change. both me and WP try to redirect, but something makes the URL remains the same and it starts a redirect loop.

Comment: the given solution doesn't work for me. changed htaccess (again) and I'm still on a loop

Comment: If the URL doesn't change, how do you know it's even redirecting in the first place? If you have cURL installed, try taking a look at the output of `curl -IL yoursite.com` to see the actual HTTP headers

Comment: hey @Mike with WWW. it gives me good headers. but without it, I only get a "Location" response, telling me to redirect again. this is the loop I am telling you about.

`HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 05:22:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Location: http://porta8080.com.br/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: It looks like it's working fine to me. I don't see any loop. However I would recommend using Location instead of Refresh to prevent the original location being put in the browser history. The redirect is also faster with a Location header.

Comment: it is caching. have a look now. stopped working last night. if I take htaccess away, it also works. this must be a problem with htaccess

Comment: It's not working for me anymore. It is redirecting to `http://porta8080.com.br/` instead of `http://www.porta8080.com.br/`

Comment: yea that's the point. and if I add a rule on htaccess, it makes no difference